# Constructor Initialization and private variables set inside constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

My constructor is suppose to only take one variable. But I'm curious if you ca initialize other variables that arent in the constructor defintion.

```
class WordAnalysis{
private:
    int timesDoubled;
    word *words;
    int wordCount;
    int index;
    void doubleArrayAndAdd(string);
    bool checkIfCommonWord(string);
    void sortData();
public:
    bool readDataFile(char*); //returns an error if file not opened
    int getWordCount();
    int getUniqueWordCount();
    int getArrayDoubling();
    void printCommonWords(int);
    void printResult(int);
    WordAnalysis(int);
    ~WordAnalysis();
```

};

Example: Would any instance of WordAnalysis now have timesdoubled as 0. and would a getter function be able to get this information without a setter?

```
WordAnalysis::WordAnalysis(int arrSize){

wordCount = arrSize;
int timesDoubled = 0;   
int index = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, you can initialize other member variables in the constructor,
even if it doesn't take the corresponding arguments.

However, in the example you gave above:

```
WordAnalysis::WordAnalysis(int arrSize){

wordCount = arrSize;
int timesDoubled = 0;   
int index = 0;
}
```

You aren't actually initializing the timesDoubled member variables, because you wrote "int" before it, which is declaring a new variable and setting that to 0.

If you want to set the classes timesDoubled variable you have to write:

```
timesDoubled = 0;
```

Or if you want to be more explicit about it, you can even write:

```
WordAnalysis::timesDoubled = 0;
```

Comment: I've spent hours trying to figure this out and it was simple as deleting the int before it. Thank you kind sir/ma'am!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can. But, you can do in-class initialization of your data members on declaration. You should use `initializer list` with constructor to initialize your required data members. All the data members are visible inside the constructor. You can assign their values in it. Technically, using `initializer list` is initialization and inside the ctor it is `assignment` when the assignment operator (=) is used.

Here's is the snippet of your code with comments:

```
class WordAnalysis
{
private:

    // Data member initialization on declaration

    int    timesDoubled  { 0 };
    word*  words         { nullptr };
    int    wordCount     { 0 };
    int    index         { 0 };

public:

    // Initializing timesDoubled using initializer list

    WordAnalysis( const int t ) : timesDoubled{ t }
    {
        // Assign default values here if need be

        index = 10; // assignment
    }

    // ...
};
```

Your compiler should be at least `C++11 compliant` to allow the in-class initializations of data members.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest defining a default constructor such as:

```
WordAnalysis()
{
   timesDoubled = 0;
    words[0] = '\0'; //assuming it's an array of char
    wordCount = 0;
    index = 0;
}
```

That way all instances of the class would be initialized.